# Pandas dataframe extracting value from json, which returned from as content(JSON) from request,

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

Pandas dataframe  extracting value from JSON, which returned from as content from request.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
import json 
import requests
import ast
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df['response'] = df.URL.apply(lambda u: requests.get(u).content)

df.head()

b'{"error":0,"short":"http:\\/\\/192.168.42.72\\/ECyKY"}'
b'{"error":0,"short":"http:\\/\\/192.168.42.72\\/IsMgE"}'
```

When we use Python without Pandas, we can just use:

```
resp = requests.get(u)
y=resp.json()
print(y)
print(y['short'])
```

to store the short value as "http://192.168.42.72/ECyKY"
spend hours trying to get it work with Pandas without luck, any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `response.get.content` directly use `response.get.json` then use [`Series.str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) to extract the value corresponding to key `short` from the dictionary and then assign it to new column `short`:

```
df['response'] = df['URL'].apply(lambda u: requests.get(u).json())
df['short'] = df['response'].str.get('short')
```

---

```
# print(df)
                                            response                       short
0  {'error': 0, 'short': 'http://192.168.42.72/EC...  http://192.168.42.72/ECyKY
1  {'error': 0, 'short': 'http://192.168.42.72/Is...  http://192.168.42.72/IsMgE
```